# Xamarin Forms C# ListView Search

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin Forms C# ListView Search
 Hello everyone,
    i want to make a search from ListView
    when i make filter by name i want suggestions appear in listview
    I tried to do this
    but not working for me !!
    i don't understand what is the problem..

Screenshot for the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaRas.jpg

```
Xamarin Forms C# ListView Search
```

Hello everyone,
    i want to make a search from ListView
    when i make filter by name i want suggestions appear in listview
    I tried to do this
    but not working for me !!
    i don't understand what is the problem..

```
    Model> echeance.cs:
    ------------

    namespace Appz.Model
    {
        public class Echeance
        {

            [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
            public int ChkId { get; set; }

            public string ChkChoise { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string ChkNumber { get; set; }

            public string ChkAmount { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string BeneficiaryName { get; set; }

            public string AgencyType { get; set; }

            public DateTime ChkDueDate { get; set; }

            public DateTime ChkReleaseDate { get; set; }

            public string ChkImage { get; set; }


        }
    }





    EcheanceView.Xaml:
    -----------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
        ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
                 x:Class="Appz.View.EcheanceView">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
                <SearchBar TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged"></SearchBar>
                <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding EcheancesList}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"  x:Name="ListEcheances" HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorVisibility="Default" ItemTapped="OnItemSelected">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ChkImage}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"  />
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding BeneficiaryName}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding AgencyType}"
                                           TextColor="Gray" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Button Text="Follow Me"
                                        BorderColor="Silver"
                                       FontSize="Small"
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       BackgroundColor="#3399ff"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                                      />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>





    EcheanceView.cs:
    ---------------

    void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {


                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
                {               
                    var echeances = conn.Table<Echeance>().ToList();
                    //ListEcheances.ItemsSource = echeances;

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
                        ListEcheances.ItemsSource = echeances;
                    else
                        ListEcheances.ItemsSource = echeances.Where(i => i.BeneficiaryName.Contains(e.NewTextValue));

                    ListEcheances.EndRefresh();

                }                    

            }
```

someone help me please
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful explanation.  Is it crashing or generating a compiler error?  Is it doing anything at all?  Have you used the debugger to verify that your events are firing and your code is executing as expected?

Comment: Screen: https://i.imgur.com/vhpt8Cp.jpg

Comment: please DO NOT post code and errors as images

Comment: you are getting a null ref exception - something in that statement is null.  You need to figure out which element and either fix it or add code to avoid it.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Put in the else case  ListEcheances.ItemsSource = echeances.Where(i => i.BeneficiaryName.Contains(e.NewTextValue)).ToList();

Comment: I think `BeneficiaryName` is null in some rows. Also, don't change the `ItemSource` just clear-and-add to the existing ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would go with for real-time filtering, is having two data sets, a backing list and a filtered collection that dynamically changes (this is the one you should bind your ListView's ItemSource to). Then just bind your Entry's Text property to your corresponding property (SearchTerm in this example). In the setter you could execute your filter/search command.

```
  private ObservableCollection<Test> filteredItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Test> FilteredItems
    {
        get => filteredItems;
        set
        {
            // Notify property changed
        }
    }

    private List<Test> allItems;
    public List<Test> AllItems
    {
        get => allItems;
        set
        {
            // Notify property changed
        }
    }

    private string searchTerm;
    public string SearchTerm
    {
        get => searchTerm;
        set
        {
            // Notify property changed
            SearchCommand.Execute(searchTerm);
        }
    }

    public Command SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<string>((searchString) =>
            {
                FilteredItems = new ObservableCollection<Test>(AllItems.Where(o => o.itemText.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())));

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems that some items have BeneficiaryName null.